# Jackson: serialize empty or null HashMap to empty Array

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, ejb

I have this class whose attributes should be serialized to JSon using Jackson:

```
public class MicroClinicalInfo {

    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, String> clinicalInfo;

    @JsonCreator
    public MicroClinicalInfo() {}

    public MicroClinicalInfo(DtoMicroSampleInfo dto) {
        this.clinicalInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(/* each clinical info entity received from EJB in dto */) {
            this.clinicalInfo.put(clinicalInfoKey, clinicalInfoDescr);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if clinical info do not exist, produced JSon is `{"clinicalInfo":{}}` but in this case frontend developer wants me to return an empty array and not an empty object. So, I should return `{"clinicalInfo":[]}`. How can I do that?
I was trying with:

```
@JsonGetter
public Map<String, String> getClinicalInfo() {
    if (this.clinicalInfo != null && !this.clinicalInfo.isEmpty()) {
        return this.clinicalInfo;
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

but I don't know how to give a uniform vision. Because serialization of a not empty HashMap is correct, but I don't know how to render it as an empty array.
Thank you all

Comment: when clinical info exists, Are you passing a json object as response ?

Comment: Yes, when clinical info exist I am asked to return a JSon object which an array key-value like this `{"clinicalInfo":{"Sector note":"left elbow"}}` which automatically happens when serializing an HashMap

Comment: then it is totally correct to send an empty object if info does not exists. This will be also helpful at front end for response handling.

Comment: They want an empty array anyway...maybe I should wrap the HashMap in an ArrayList? something like `private List<Map<String, String>> clinicalInfo = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>()` ?

Comment: if you have to do this then return Collections.emptyList(); will also help.